# Using gatsby-image in mdx file with gatsby-plugin-page-creator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-image

For my gatsby project I use Mdx with gatsby-plugin-page-creator to create my pages without a template specific query.

Most pages have an image on top of the page, so I want to add that via mdx (frontmatter?).

I have tried the gatsby-remark-images way, but the problem with that is that it only works in the "html". The goal is to add the image separate from the "html" so I can use a sharp image on the (pageContext.frontmatter ?) side.

```
// gatsby-config.js
{
      resolve: "gatsby-plugin-page-creator",
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/src/data/mdx`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-mdx',
      options: {
        defaultLayouts: {
          default: require.resolve("./src/templates/mdx.js"),
        },
        gatsbyRemarkPlugins: [
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
            options: {
              // It's important to specify the maxWidth (in pixels) of
              // the content container as this plugin uses this as the
              // base for generating different widths of each image.
              maxWidth: 992,
              backgroundColor: 'transparent',
              withWebp: true,
            },
          },
        ]
      },

    },


// example-page.md

---
excludeFromNav: false
excludeFromFooterNav: false
name: Contact
image: ./logo.jpg
---

import Maps from '../../components/maps';

<Maps />


// mdx.js
export default ({ children, data, ...props }) => {
  console.log('RENERING mdx.js', data, props);
  return (
    <Layout>
      {children}   
    </Layout>
  )
};
```

in the `mdx.js` file a have my `frontmatter`, it has an image, but the image is not sharp.

Is there a way the create sharp images via mdx? Are there ways a havent thought of that maybe work better?

Thanx in advance!

Joost

Comment: In your page that you want to display the image from the frontmatter, how are you loading the image?

i.e. are you obtaining the image via a graphql query? If so, what does that query look like?

Comment: Take a look at the Gatsby tutorial, particularly part 7 - https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/tutorial/part-7/